# Elasticsearch multiple queries

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

i would like to get distinct ip's for example today and where campaigne="2"
in sql: 
select distinct ip
from test
where timestamp >= "2016-01-16" ... AND
fk_campaign_id = "2";

this works but json validator outputs "Duplicate key, names should be unique."

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "distinct_ip":{  
         "cardinality":{  
            "field":"ip"
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{  
      "range":{  
         "timestamp":{  
            "gte":"2016-01-16T00:00:00",
            "lt":"2016-01-17T00:00:00"
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{  
      "match":{  
         "fk_campaign_id":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

But if i try to build this query in php, var_dump($params) returns me back json only with one "query", may be because of Duplicate key???

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "distinct_ip":{  
         "cardinality":{  
            "field":"ip"
         }
      }
   },
```

part with range is not here?!?!?

```
   "query":{  
      "match":{  
         "fk_campaign_id":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your json `query` is a duplicate key. You need to use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) whenever you have multiple conditions. since you have **AND** condition you need to use `must clause`. This is the right syntax

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2016-01-16T00:00:00",
              "lt": "2016-01-17T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fk_campaign_id": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_ip": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you recommend any literature for Elasticsearch? Tanks

Comment: One of the most important thing about ES is its data structure i.e [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html), its [analysis process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html), its [internals](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up), that link also has links to other papers. This is a good starting point IMO.